# How to add a rdlc group's totals row for an outer group's totals row

Tags: sum, rdlc

I have a 2-level group report (rdlc). The inner group (GroupA) has in its totals row, totals of all record values, except one value which is the same for all records and for which that is the value I need to show(let's call that X). So the totals row looks like
**Sum,Sum,....X**
To do this I use Sum(Fields!,"GroupA") for all cells except this one, which is Fields!X.Value;

The outer group (Group B) must add all these values and display their sums in its totals row. The desired output should be:
Sum,Sum,.....Sum
So for all other fields, I use Sum(Fields!,"Group2"). 
What must I use for the X field? If I use Sum(Fields!X.Value,"Group2") it will add X as many numbers as there are records, where I want to add X for each group.

I really would appreciate a quick answer on this as I have to fix this problem yesterday :)
thanks
c.